# ID generation in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, ddl

I'm trying to create a table in Oracle as follows:

```
create table person (
person_id       number(5) generated always as identity
            minvalue 1
            maxvalue 99999
            increment by 1 start with 1
            cycle
            cache 10,
firstname   varchar(10),
lastname    varchar(10));
```

This works all fine, but when I try something like this:

```
insert into person
values ('firstname', 'lastname');
```

I'm getting an error. When I try putting in a number where the ID should be, I get a different error.

I'm confused because I originally thought that formatting the person_id in this way automatically generated unique ID values, so that I wouldn't be able to put them in.

I'm also a bit confused on how this all fits into JDBC. If I'm working with Java and I insert a tuple into such a table, how am I able to get the generated ID into my Java program? I can't search by first and last name, because there could be two people with the same name.

Comment: Please post the error you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to list the columns for an `insert`:

```
insert into person(firstname, lastname)
    values ('firstname', 'lastname');
```

The fact that the column is generated doesn't affect the syntax of the `insert`.  So, with no columns, the insert is the same as:

```
insert into person(person_id, firstname, lastname)
    values ('firstname', 'lastname');
```

And with two values and three columns, you are getting an error.